# The getter 'email' was called on null. Even after checking for null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am creating a chatting flutter app called FlashChat from AppBrewery.
In the welcome screen, I want the initial route to go directly to the chat route if the user is already logged in.

```
_auth.currentUser() == null ? '/' : '/chat'
```

I used this ternary operator so it would only go the chat screen if there is a currentUser. However, I think it is still trying to call the route to go to the /chat screen and that is what is calling email on null, as this code is in my '/chat' route:

```
final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
          messageText, messageSender, messageSender == loggedInUser.email);
```

Why is it going to the /chat route and accessing .email on a null when the ternary operator should stop it from going?

Comment: _auth?.currentUser() == null ? '/' : '/chat'

Comment: What does your MaterialApp widget look like?

Comment: return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: _auth.currentUser() == null ? '/' : '/chat',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
        '/registration': (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
        '/chat': (context) => ChatScreen(),
      },
    );

Answer (score 0):

`auth.currentUser()` will always return a `Future<AuthResult>`, you need to use `async/await` to check if the `AuthResult` will be null or not.

```
void getUser() async {
  Future<AuthResult> user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   user == null ? '/' : '/chat';
}
```

Comment: I added the method, but it just doesn't have any apparent functionality. I feel like it should, but every time I restart the app it just goes to the '/' route.

Comment: It should retrieve the current user and then check if null or not, where are u calling it?